# use opencv to draw my bounding boxes in the image, but the bbox never shows

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, opencv, python

This is part of my code. Basically, I trained my own model, and I want to predict where the boxes are and draw them, and output the images with the bbox. But the bbox never shows...

```
def get_transform(train):
    transforms = []
    transforms.append(Transforms.ToTensor())
    if train:
        transforms.append(Transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5))
    return Transforms.Compose(transforms)


def showbbox(model, image):

    model.eval()
    image = ToTensor()(image).unsqueeze(0)
    image = Variable(image)
    with torch.no_grad():
        prediction = model(image)

    print(prediction)

    image = image.permute(0, 2,3,1)
    image = (image * 255).byte().data.cpu()
    image =np.array(image)

    for i in range(prediction[0]['boxes'].cpu().shape[0]):
        xmin = round(prediction[0]['boxes'][i][0].item())
        ymin = round(prediction[0]['boxes'][i][1].item())
        xmax = round(prediction[0]['boxes'][i][2].item())
        ymax = round(prediction[0]['boxes'][i][3].item())

        label = prediction[0]['labels'][i].item()

        if label == 1:
            image = np.ascontiguousarray(image)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(image, 'mark_type_1', (xmin, ymin), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0),
                        thickness=2)

cv2.imwrite("test.png", image)
image_name = 'image'
cv2.namedWindow(image_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
```

I also attach my log here: it shows the coordinates of the predicted bboxes:

```
[{'boxes': tensor([[ 205.3901,  874.5291, 2172.6992, 3289.5364],
        [  10.5118,  837.6425,  977.6479, 3137.6086],
        [   0.0000,   45.9050, 1582.4817, 2750.2344],
        [ 558.1544,  133.1127, 2530.4922, 2671.6353],
        [ 917.5895, 1817.0457, 2532.4092, 3297.6543],
        [1203.6671,  660.2758, 2538.5496, 3149.8977],
        [ 205.8660,   14.9926, 2237.4023, 1690.5226],
        [1062.8268,    0.0000, 2541.5366, 1408.9767]]), 'labels': tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), 'scores': tensor([0.2706, 0.2349, 0.2335, 0.2269, 0.2250, 0.2125, 0.2105, 0.1781])}]
```

Answer (score 0):

two different issues.

1. A matter of python and scope of variable names.

you can pass `image` into your function. now a variable name in the function, which just happens to also be named `image`, refers to the object you just passed in.

you can change the object inside of the function, i.e. change the contents. you will observe the changes to the object from the outside because in both places you refer to the same object.

but when you assign a new object to the *variable in the function*, the caller/outside will not be affected. the variable name on the outside still refers to the original object.

you solve this by returning the new object from within your function, and assigning the return value of the call to the variable in the caller scope (which is the global scope in your case).

2. you never call your `showbbox` and `get_transform` functions? you need to call them if you want them to do anything.